# Remove sitemaps URL from Google results

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

My webpage with Sitemaps http://foo.com/oddname.php appears within the results of Google if I search "oddname site:foo.com".

How could I remove it from appearing in the results without using 'robots.txt'? I do not want anybody to know which my sitemaps URL is.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the noindex metatag.

> Block search indexing with 'noindex'
>   You can prevent a page from appearing in Google Search by including a noindex meta tag in the page's HTML code, or by returning a 'noindex' header in the HTTP request. When Googlebot next crawls that page and see the tag or header, Googlebot will drop that page entirely from Google Search results, regardless of whether other sites link to it.

See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710